# Siegward of Catarina quest can't find Siegward

Tags: ps4, dark-souls-3

So, I open the cell before I did the part in the cathedral where you talk to him and give him the armor. The next step in the questline is rescue him from the cell, but I alredy open that cell before. Where can I find him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give him the armor. You will NOT fail if you open the cell first (source: personal experience, twice).

(possible spoilers)

Just go back and talk with him in the well *after* you have opened the big double doors shortcut up top near the Boss and the Giants. After you then talk to him, go back up, through the double doors and to the right and look for a guy in the Onion Knight Armor.

If he is not there, then the second place the imposter will be is the Tower behind Firelink shrine (buy the key for 20k at the shrine Old Lady vendor). He will lock you in and then have a dialog with you.

After you get back to Firelink, go up by the exit to the tower, and the imposter will be there. Buy the onion armor set off him (shield not needed), and then go and give it to Siegward.

The next place siegward will be found is by a fire in Irithyll before the Dungeon. It is right after the tunnel with all the spider-like ladies, where the Estus Soup is. You had to walk past here to get to the Pontiff Boss. Talk to him there and then he will be in the cell, whether you opened it already or not.

Comment: Note: you *may* have to kill the Deacons Boss(es) to trigger the Tower lock-in event mentioned above. He does not always spawn in the Armor by the giants, but he will spawn by the tower.

Comment: Still can't find him. The last thing I did was giving him the armor. After that, I did nothing else with him. For what I know, the next part where he should be is in the cell. But he is not there. (I went to all the places you say, nothing)

Comment: After the well, he is by the fire in Irithyll. I know you said you went to all the places, but then you said he should be in the cell after the well. So, just clarifying. Did you get the armor from Patches?

Comment: You were right. He is just in front of the fire. Thanks man! I was in another place where I though you mean about the spiders. But now I found it, thanks again.

Comment: Hey no problem GG